# Fluent validation how to return unique errors when validating a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I have:

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Items).NotEmpty()
            .WithState(x => new Error("Message1", "Message2"))
            .ForEach(x =>
                x.SetValidator(new ItemValidator())
            );
```

and

```
 public SignleItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithState(x => new Error("Message1", "Message2"));
        RuleFor(x => x.Category).NotEmpty().WithState(x => new Error("Message1", "Message2"));
    }
```

My problem is that when 'Name' or 'Category' is empty for several list items then 'Fluentvalidation' returns copies of the same error for each item. Is it possible to return each error only once?

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

For a single message the list should be made as a single property

```
RuleFor(x => x.Items).NotEmpty().Must(s => 
   !s.Any(item => item.Name.IsNullOrEmpty()))
   .WithMessage("Message");
```